# Android: how to l launch BBM app with a given Pin

Tags: android, bb-messenger

My android app is for buy and sell stuffs. When seller post an ad and provide his BBM Pin, I like to display a button, like "Contact me via BBM (Pin: 12345)"

When a buyer click on the button, I want to be able to launch the BBM app which then show a chat page that allows Buyer to chat with Seller
(Assume the buyer has already installed BBM app in his device)

Step 1: I've already managed to launch the BBM app by using its package name

Step 2: how to open a chat page for Buyer to chat with Seller?
        If this is not doable, can I at least show the invite page 
        with pre-filled Seller's PIN there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet supported for BBM on Android or iOS (it is possible today on a BlackBerry 10 device).

Comment: Thank you Mark. Is it possible for you to give me a roughly estimate when this feature will be available?